# Running time of the statements and why

Tags: algorithm

Hello I am new to algorithms and would like to ask about the whether the following statements are true or false and why?

```
(1) n − 2 log n = Ω(n)
(2) n^2logn = Θ(n^2)
(3) 2n^2 + 4n - 17 = O(n^3)
(4) n^3 + 7n - 21 = Θ(n^2)
```

I would be really yhankful if somebody can help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: At least one of them is false. You're probably going to have to add some commentary showing some effort on your own part before many people will help much though.

Comment: Yea but I am not sure what comment should I give, because I can't still understand how these running times are working

Answer (score 0):

I's all about math, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation, I don't know much about Big Omega,, but I would say

```
(1) would say true from what I read on wikipedia about the big Omega notation
(2) O(n²log(n))
(3) O(n²)
(4) O(n³)
```

Comment: Ok thank you for the help anyways I will skip this exercise don't like it much